# Defining a function through an ODE containing unspecified operators

Tags: differential-equations, functions, nonlinear, variable-definitions, operators

I want to do some algebra using a function only defined through a DE containing unspecified operators. The DE is
    $$
\partial_zu(z) = \left[\hat{D}+\hat{N}(z,u)\right] u(z).
$$
Here $u$ lives in some function space (it is bounded, integrable, continuously differentiable,...) and $\hat{D},\hat{N}$ are bounded operators on said function space that don't necessarilly commute and only $\hat{D}$ is linear. How do I define $u$ in Mathematica?

My reason for asking this question: I derived that for $u_I(z):=e^{-(z-z')\hat{D}}\cdot u(z)$ that
\begin{align}
\partial_zu_I(z) &= \hat{N}_I(z,u_I)\cdot u_I(z),\\
\hat{N}_I(z,u_I) :&= e^{-(z-z')\hat{D}}\cdot \hat{N}(z,u_I)\cdot e^{(z-z')\hat{D}}.
\end{align}
I was wondering how to do such derivations with Mathematica.

Comment: Do you want a numerical (approximate) solver or a symbolic (exact) solver?

Comment: In [`DifferentialRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DifferentialRoot.html) one finds embedded in examples, the use of `Function` to code an operator.

Comment: This is all symbolic. Nothing is numerically specified, so nothing numerical is even an option. It's purely about rewriting, using algebra/calculus.